# Get lat lon under NAD83

Tags: python, raster

I am trying to read in lat long information from a raster image.

I used rasterio package to open the image:

```
cdl = rasterio.open('2018_30m_cdls/2018_30m_cdls.img')
cdl.xy(1, 1)
```

The output is:

```
(-2356050.0, 3172560.0)
```

I looked at the crs of this image:

```
CRS.from_wkt('PROJCS["Albers Conical Equal Area",
GEOGCS["NAD83",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
SPHEROID["GRS1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
TOWGS84[0,0,0,-0,-0,-0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],
PROJECTION["Albers_Conic_Equal_Area"],
PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",29.5],
PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",45.5],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",23],
PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",-96],
PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
UNIT["meters",1]]')
```

What projection I am at? I want to have lat long under NAD83, epsg:4269. It seems I am already under this projection? But why the lat long is not showing something like -90, 40?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

The

```
'PROJCS["Albers Conical Equal Area"
```

indicates that the CRS is a projected coordinate system as opposed to an unprojected one (as is NAD83).

That's why you are getting X, Y coordinates in meters instead of latitude, longitude pairs in degrees. Explained by the last line of the image CRS:

```
UNIT["meters",1]]')
```

Apparently the system is [SR-ORG:8538](https://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/8538/) **LNF FF Slope** with the following PROJ4 string definition:

```
+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs
```

... but you can check the image CRS that is defined by executing:

```
cdl.crs
```

The easiest way to get NAD83 coordinates is to reproject the image to `EPSG:4269` using `rio` utility:

```
rio edit-info --crs EPSG:4269 2018_30m_cdls.tif
```

Note that you'll probably need to convert from `img` format to `tif`, first.

Comment: NAD83, like WGS84, is a datum, not a projection. It makes no sense to say "that NAD83 is unprojected" --- as it obviously can be as you can see in the question and you show yourself for NAD27.

Comment: Yes, but using NAD83, WGS84 or another datum does not mean that your coordinates are longitude/latitude. These are datums. They describe the model of the earth. Not the projection, or lack thereof. Two different concepts that are often confused, as you do.(and note that you show an aea projection based on the NAD83 datum.)